# Error compiling code which creates Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice object

Tags: c++, multithreading, eigen, tensor

Eigen Version 3.3.90

gcc Version 5.4.0

---

I'm currently trying to add multi-threading support to my Eigen Tensor project, and I've hit a problem creating the ThreadPoolDevice required to evaluate tensor operations.

A minimal code example which produces the error is shown below. This is based upon the examples [shown here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title3) in the Eigen Docs.

```
#include <iostream>
#define EIGEN_USE_THREADS
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/ThreadPool>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Eigen Version " << EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION << "." << EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION << "." << EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION << std::endl;

    // Create the Eigen ThreadPoolDevice.
    Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice my_device(4 /* number of threads to use */);

    Eigen::Tensor<float, 2> a(40, 40);
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 2> b(40, 40);

    // Now just use the device when evaluating expressions.
    Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 1> product_dims = { Eigen::IndexPair<int>(1, 0) };
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 2> c;
    c.device(my_device) = a.contract(b, product_dims);

    std::cout << "Result was " << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the error message shown below:

```
thread_pool_tests.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
thread_pool_tests.cpp:12:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice::ThreadPoolDevice(int)’
  Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice my_device(4 /* number of threads to use */);
                                                                    ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:103:0,
                 from thread_pool_tests.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorDeviceThreadPool.h:55:3: note: candidate: Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice::ThreadPoolDevice(Eigen::ThreadPoolInterface*, int, Eigen::Allocator*)
   ThreadPoolDevice(ThreadPoolInterface* pool, int num_cores, Allocator* allocator = NULL)
   ^
/usr/local/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorDeviceThreadPool.h:55:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorDeviceThreadPool.h:53:8: note: candidate: constexpr Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice::ThreadPoolDevice(const Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice&)
 struct ThreadPoolDevice {
        ^
/usr/local/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorDeviceThreadPool.h:53:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice&’
/usr/local/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorDeviceThreadPool.h:53:8: note: candidate: constexpr Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice::ThreadPoolDevice(Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice&&)
/usr/local/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorDeviceThreadPool.h:53:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice&&’
```

It appears that the ThreadPoolDevice constructor in this version is also expecting a pointer to an object derived from ThreadPoolInterface. But I cannot find any examples of this form. Does anyone know how I can solve this and start working with ThreadPoolDevices in my application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the error message and `ThreadPoolDevice(ThreadPoolInterface* pool, int num_cores) : pool_(pool), num_threads_(num_cores) { }` [here, on line 107](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/TensorDeviceThreadPool_8h_source.html) I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that you need to create and pass in the address of a `ThreadPool` to the constructor.  There is a `ThreadPool` typedef at the top of that source file.

DISCLAIMER -- I have not tested this.  This is based on examination of source code files.  [NonBlockingThreadPool.h](https://github.com/rocmarchive/eigen-upstream/blob/master/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/ThreadPool/NonBlockingThreadPool.h)

```
Eigen::ThreadPool pool(4/*number of threads*/);
Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice my_device(&pool, 4 /* number of threads to use */);
```

I wonder if your example documentation is out of date, or just wrong...

Comment: I'll give it a got and let you know what happens.

Comment: That's fixed it. I guess the API has changed a bit since that documentation was written. Thanks for your help.